# Usage bluetooth sockets in kernel module

Tags: sockets, server, bluetooth, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm curious is there any possibility to make a bluetooth server in kernel module. I've seen udp server, but I need exactly a bluetooth one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel code can call sock_create_kern() to create sockets of any family, including AF_BLUETOOTH.

Code under net/bluetooth/rfcomm/ already does it.